# Add a custom framework in a custom framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, frameworks

I am developing an iOS Real Framework with XCode. This `Framework (A)` needs an external `framework (B)` to compile. For example:

```
A FRAMEWORK
+Frameworks
 -B FRAMEWORK
```

It is imported in A by using:

```
#import<BFRAMEWORK/bframework.h>
```

I create the `A.framework` to be linked in a project.

The problem is when I link this `A Framework` in a project. The project returns `"BFRAMEWORK/bframework.h`" not found.

I want to include `B framework` in `A.framework` so not to need to add `B framework` also in my project. For example:

```
MY PROJECT
+Frameworks
 -A.Framework (with B Framework included inside).
```

Do you know how to do this? or another way to do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, It's possible to create nested framework. Please see answer here:- http://stackoverflow.com/a/27638841/1582217

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create an Umbrella framework in iOS sdk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484997/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-ios-sdk)

Comment: Look at the creation dates @Mohd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to create this structure with iOS-Universal-Framework: https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework.

I created a Static iOS Framework 'FrameworkB' with 1 method, which is imported in a second Static iOS Framework 'Framework A' with 1 method that's calling FrameworkB's method. I then created an iPad app which imports FrameworkA and calls the method. Code runs fine and prints from FrameworkA (which fetches from FrameworkB) and of course FrameworkB is not imported. Please note that all frameworks have to be built for the same profile (i used iPad), otherwise you'll get linker errors.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you add BFramework in compile sources?
Or add headers in header search paths?
or set dependency in build settings.

Answer (score -2):

I think you are looking for `OTHER_LDFLAGS = -ObjC`

Comment: This is not a helpful answer, should be added in the comments.

Comment: this have nothing to do with the question.