# How to create an umbrella framework in iOS SDK?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, frameworks

I want to create an umbrella framework in iOS SDK. My requirements are:

I have a framework called "Framework A", I want to create another framework called "Framework B". I want to add "Framework A" into "Framework B" as a sub-framework and users only need to import "Framework B" in their project to use both "Framework A" and "Framework B". In other words, "Framework B" will work as a wrapper for "Framework A". I read out from Apple via following link regarding framework creations:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html

but it doesn't expose the way to create an umbrella framework.

Please suggest step by step method to create an umbrella framework.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a framework inside another framework (Umbrella Framework)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681435/how-to-add-a-framework-inside-another-framework-umbrella-framework)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

We all know that creating umbrella framework is highly discouraged by Apple. But apple also says it’s possible via Xcode. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/CreationGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002254-BAJHGGGA

I achieved creating umbrella framework via these simple approach on Xcode 5.1. We just need to do take care of some special configuration to linking sub-framework to umbrella framework. Here was my approach:-

1. Install real `Static iOS Framework` on Xcode 5.1 from the method described here:- https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework.

Now the ‘Static iOS Framework’ can be created using the new option in Xcode.

[image]

2. Create a `Static iOS Framework` and change the `Target-> Build Settings-> Architectures-> Architectures` settings to Standard architectures. This will create the framework with all the Standard Architectures.

[image]

3. Adjust Public Header files in `Target-> Build Phase-> Copy Headers`. We can set the header file visibility here.

[image]

4. Link SubFramework to UmbrellaFramework in `Target->Build Phase -> Link Binary With Libraries`. We may also need to link other standard framework depending on our use.

[image]
[image]

5. We may also need to add Bundle Resources in `Target-> Build Phase-> Copy Bundle Resources` if we need.

[image]

6. We may also need to add `-ObjC` to `Target-> Build Settings->Linking-> Other Linker Flag`, as we may need to load a large subFramework where there are many categories to load or need to load additional frameworks also.

[image]

7. Add `Copy File` using `Target-> Build Phases-> +-> New Copy File Build Phase`.

[image]

8. Change it’s Destination to `Frameworks` and add SubFramework.framework there. This will copy SubFramework to Umbrella Framework.

[image]
[image]

9. For the demo I Added two demo methods in UmbrellaFramework class. One to demonstrating umbrella framework method call and one for calling subFramework method.

[image]
[image]

10. Select `iOS Device` and Archive the UmbrellaFramework project from `Menu->Product->Archive`. This will create our umbrella framework and that’s all.

[image]

11. Now it’s time to create a new demo project, and link it with UmbrellaFramework.

[image]

12. Just import UmbrellaFramework header and call the two methods. It will show the Hello messages in log window.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, I've no success with Xcode 6 till date. 'iOS Universal Framework' https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework should also add support for Xcode 6.

Comment: I've tried that one, but haven't had any luck with it either. It really is a god damn shame that Apple documents the usage of umbrella frameworks, yet fail to deliver any sort of guidance as to how to create them.

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi. getting subframework not found error.

Comment: Did anyone experiment this issue when using the umbrella framework in the final app?

dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/embeddedframework.framework/embeddedframework
  Referenced from: /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/EA127B01-9444-4660-B0F6-1A75A74CB330/sampleapp.app/Frameworks/umbrellaframework.framework/umbrellaframework
  Reason: image not found

Comment: Does not work for me in Xcode 8, still get linker errors

Comment: same here  and have issue in import

Comment: Any idea how to workaround the copy phase not including the subframework's headers? I need access to some of the headers in the parent framework's public headers.

Comment: @malhal Have you found any solution for your issue? I'm facing the same problem at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

To create a Swift based Umbrella Framework that contains a Sub-Framework you can follow the step-by-step guide written down here: [Umbrella framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41397746/umbrella-framework/41815368#41815368)