# How to link sub frameworks in an umbrella framework?

Tags: ios, frameworks

I am trying to create a static umbrella framework which holds various 3rd party sub frameworks. So i've followed this tutorial below:

[How to create an umbrella framework in iOS SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27484997/how-to-create-an-umbrella-framework-in-ios-sdk)

Unfortunately when adding the static umbrella framework into another project I get various "undefined symbol" errors from the sub-frameworks.

When I link the sub frameworks again in the "link binary with libraries" like the image below it does work. But how can I prevent this to be needed? I would like an external developer only to add my Umbrella framework to his project.

[image: link binary with libraries image]

Comment: I think you will always need to add the sub frameworks in the "link binary with libraries" section when adding a new framework.

Comment: hmm maybe i don't understand, isn't that the whole idea behind an umbrella framework that a subframework is only used by the parent framework and an external project cannot directly link to it?

Comment: @martijn, have you solved this? I am suffering from the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to make an "umbrella framework" is to use all the sub-frameworks as static libraries in your framework. That way, these sub-frameworks will become part of your own framework and external developers won't need to embed any sub-frameworks.

Comment: Note that this is very dangerous if the consumer of the your framework uses any of the same sub-frameworks. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365578/why-are-umbrella-frameworks-discouraged for more.